# RequireJS issue with Config File

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, requirejs

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "/",
   paths:{
       "jquery": "/assets/backbone/assets/backbone/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery",
       "underscore": "/assets/backbone/js/libs/underscore/underscore",
       "backbone": "/assets/backbone/js/libs/backbone/backbone"
   }
});

require(['assets/backbone/templates/views/app'], function(AppView){
    new AppView;
});
```

Error

```
GET http://domain.com/assets/backbone/assets/backbone/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery.js 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If i remove assets/backbone/ from assets/backbone/templates/views/app

```
GET http://domain.com/templates/views/app 500 (Internal Server Error) require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: /templates/views/app
```

..... Why does it Duplicate twice or dont show at all???

Comment: Can you post your backbone view code? Might be something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guest your jquery's path is wrong.

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "/",
   paths:{
       // probably this line is wrong
       // "jquery": "/assets/backbone/assets/backbone/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery",
       "jquery": "/assets/backbone/js/libs/jquery/src/jquery",
       "underscore": "/assets/backbone/js/libs/underscore/underscore",
       "backbone": "/assets/backbone/js/libs/backbone/backbone"
   }
});
```